# Getting the same fill patterns on different layers to match (set common base point) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, overlapping-features, fill

I got a similar problem as described here: [Using multiple line fill patterns with common base point in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403071/using-multiple-line-fill-patterns-with-common-base-point-in-qgis)

I want two layers with the same symbology to overlap seamlessly. However, it looks like this:

[image]

However, in my case, the symbologies are on two or more different layers, so a geometry-generator doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The cartographer asks "why on Earth would you wanna do that?!".

Comment: You can use a geometry generator that adds a common point to all geometries, so all patterns have the same origin: `union($geometry, make_point(-180,-90))`. The coordinates used in `make_point` need to be to the south west of all of your features.

Comment: @jake: Thank you! That was it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did solve it with the solution from @jake:

> You can use a geometry generator that adds a common point to all geometries, so all patterns have the same origin: `union($geometry, make_point(-180,-90))`. The coordinates used in `make_point()` need to be to the south west of all of your features.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate the geometries of each layer and than combine them using [`collect_geometries()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#collect-geometries). The final expression could look like this - replace `'poly1'`, `'poly2'` etc. with the names of your polygon layers:

```
collect_geometries( 
    aggregate('poly1', 'collect', $geometry),
    aggregate('poly2', 'collect', $geometry),
    aggregate('poly3', 'collect', $geometry)
)
```

*Screenshot 1: original polygons (3 layers):*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: the collected polygons with a common line-pattern:*
[image]